# Give multiple elements unique classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of span elements and I want to give them unique classes. like one, two, three four. Then repeat for next container with the same class. Its this possible with jQuery/vanilla js? Or rather, how do I do this?

My HTML:

```
<div class="ccbnOutline">
    <span></span> -- give class one
    <span></span> -- give class two
    <span></span> -- give class three
    <span></span> -- give class four
</div>

<div class="ccbnOutline">
    <span></span> -- give class one
    <span></span> -- give class two
    <span></span> -- give class three
    <span></span> -- give class four
</div>
```

Comment: everything is possible

Comment: Selecting the elements using jQuery/vanilla and then iterating over them seems to be a possible solution. Did you write any code to solve it? What's the exact problem, if any?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var arr=["one","two","three","four"];
        $('.ccbOutline').each(function(ix,val) {
               val.find('span').each(function(i,v){
          $(this).addClass(arr[i]);
        });
    });
```

Comment: In this case I would select on `$(".ccbOutline span")` so you don't select every single span on the page.

Comment: @madalin ivascu This kinda works - but I have  mutliple .ccbOutline containers - this keeps giving classes troughout the containers. Both containers have the same amount of spans, 4 each. in each container I want the spans to have the same classes ,one, two ,three ,four. Now the numbers keep going. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you need a mapping array like this

```
var arr=["one","two","three","four"]; // "five","six " and so an
$('.ccbOutline  span').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass(arr[i]);
});
```